# NetLogo: selecting random one turtle from two kinds

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, suppose AAA and BBB are the names of turtles.

```
one-of AAA in-radius 1
```

will pick one turtle among AAA that are within radius 1. Similarly,

```
one-of BBB in-radius 1
```

will pick one turtle among BBB that are within radius 1.

I want to pick random one turtle from the group of AAA and BBB. For eaxample, if there are 3 AAA's and 2 BBB's that satisfy the condition. I want to pick random one turtle from the 5 turtles. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select only turtles of specific breeds you can use the "with" primitive to check if the actual turtle is a member of one of the breeds:

```
one-of turtles in-radius 1 with [member? self aaa = true or member? self bbb = true]
```

If you have a large number of breeds it would make sense to create an unified agentset which contains all the turtles of the breeds you want to include:

```
let as_and_bs (turtle-set aaa bbb)
...
one-of as_and_bs in-radius 1
```

Comment: `member? self aaa = true` can be shortened to simply `breed = aaa`.